# CSS disappear when printing

Tags: html, css

[image]

why my CSS disappear when printing. i need to position the amount in the right

please help

Comment: no code no links , how we can check your problem ?

Comment: Add your code here,otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

This happen when your link tags have `media="screen"` set. This means that the CSS will only apply onscreen and not when the page is printed. To make the CSS apply for printing also, set `media="all"` or just omit the media attribute. You can also set media="print" for print-only styles. Hope this helps!

If you want to use same css file for screen and anyother output device than :

`<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">`

Else you can use separate css file for different purpose:

`<link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">
<link type="text/css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" href="/print.css">`

**Note**: To save ink, browsers don't print backgrounds. I would recommend that you create a print stylesheet. For print, many elements of the page can be hidden, like the search box and navigation.

Answer (score 1):

By checking the image, I understands that you are trying to print your css in pdf format for print. But the issue is that normal css wouldn't work on pdf. You need to create another css having media="print" attribute, As shown below.

```
<link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
<link type="text/css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/print.css">
```

copy and paste the main styles and change any sections you don't want to print as display:none. Alter other styles to suit.

Answer (score 0):

apply same css into "@media print". It is used to apply css into printing options